# How to turn off the app orientation of iOS app

Tags: ios

I want to disable the landscape orientation for my new iOS quiz app. in android it is very simple and i know how to do it but i am not able to find suitable file in iOS from where I can stop the app orientation. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]It is more simple in iOS as well select your project name in Xcode and navigate to general and in deployment, info unchecks the landscape left and right that's it.

Comment: thanks Vishal sharma

Comment: Does this still allow for programmatically unlocking at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the name of your project
2. Choose your target from the **Targets** list
3. Go to the **General** tab
4. In the **Deployment Info** section, select the orientations that you want to keep

[image: Deployment Info]

Comment: thanks Carpsen90 both the answer are working

Comment: @MaryJBurr Glad I could help! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) could be useful.

Comment: how could i change the app name

Comment: Change the `Display Name` in the `Identity` section